# Dashboarding in R for Business Analytics Purposes

Tags: r, visualization, dashboard

Looking for resources that can help me learn to build advanced and interactive dashboards in R. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Using R you can master Shiny to build such interactive dashboards.
Some of the most and best common materials that will help you to do so;

- **Mastering Shiny Book** by Hadley Wickham https://mastering-shiny.org/
- **Getting Started with Shiny** https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/